# can't find issues identified by nag

Tags: fonts, fancyhdr, nag

I am somewhat new to LaTeX, but am currently working on a project (trying to use pdflatex for automated .pdf report rendering).  I just learned about

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
```

today, and have made a lot of changes based on its suggestions, but there are still four nag complaints being reported, and I can't find the cause.  Can anyone show me what I still need to do to fix my source document?

I am running texlive and get the same results on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS and another Debian-based installation.

-

Here are the nag errors:

> Package nag Warning: Command \sl is an old LaTeX 2.09 command. 
>   (nag)                Use \slshape or \textsl instead on input line 131.
>
> Package nag Warning: Command \sl is an old LaTeX 2.09 command. 
>   (nag)                Use \slshape or \textsl instead on input line 131.
>
> Package nag Warning: Command \sl is an old LaTeX 2.09 command. 
>   (nag)                Use \slshape or \textsl instead on input line 209.
>
> Package nag Warning: Command \sl is an old LaTeX 2.09 command. 
>   (nag)                Use \slshape or \textsl instead on input line 209.
>
> Package nag Warning: 4 complaints in total.

And the scrubbed source file:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.4in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu,booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newlength{\defaultparindent}
\setlength{\defaultparindent}{\the\parindent}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.eps}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{18pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\textbf{\Large Board~of~Revision~Standard~Report}}
\cfoot{\textbf{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\section*{Salient~Facts\label{sec:salientfacts}}
\end{center}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{rLrL}
Case~\#:&2012-xxxxx&\hspace{1em}Phone:&\mbox{removed}\\
Owner: &REMOVED&Agent:&\\
Appraiser:&ZEIGLER JR., GARY&&\\
\end{tabulary}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Address:}~~REMOVED
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {rlrrrrr}
\toprule
&\textbf{Parcel}&\textbf{Land}&\textbf{Building}&\textbf{OBXF}&\textbf{TOTAL}&\textbf{Sought~Value}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{7}{l}{{\ldots continued from previous page}}\\
&\textbf{Parcel}&\textbf{Land}&\textbf{Building}&\textbf{OBXF}&\textbf{TOTAL}&\textbf{Sought~Value}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
\endhead
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{r}{{Continued on next page\ldots}}\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
1.)&removed&\$7,300&\$26,100&\$0&\$33,400&\$8,000\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
\addlinespace
&TOTALS&\$7,300&\$26,100&\$0&\$33,400&\textbf{\$8,000}\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{center}

\vspace{-2.0\baselineskip}

\begin{center}
\section*{Sale~History~(for~past~three~years)\label{sec:salehistory}}
\end{center}
\nopagebreak
\vspace{-1.0\baselineskip}
\nopagebreak
\begin{center}
\begin{longtabu}to \textwidth{X[l]X[l]crrcc}
\toprule
\textbf{Grantor~(Seller)}&\textbf{Grantee~(Buyer)}&\textbf{Date}&\textbf{Sale~Price}&\textbf{\#}&\textbf{AL}&\textbf{Qual}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{7}{l}{{Continued from previous page\ldots}}\\
\textbf{Grantor~(Seller)}&\textbf{Grantee~(Buyer)}&\textbf{Date}&\textbf{Sale~Price}&\textbf{\#}&\textbf{AL}&\textbf{Qual}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{r}{{Continued on next page\ldots}}\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\multicolumn{7}{c}{{No Sales in the past three years}}\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{center}

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{lXr}
Split/Combine/Annex:&&N/A\\
Prior~Board~of~Revision:&&N/A\\
Nature~of~Complaint:&&OVERVALUATION\\
\end{tabu}

\vspace{2.0\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\section*{Attachments\label{sec:attachments}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{lc}

\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2.0\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\section*{Index\label{sec:index}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabu}{lc}
Salient Facts&Page \pageref{sec:salientfacts}\\
Sale History&Page \pageref{sec:salehistory}\\
Attachments&Page \pageref{sec:attachments}\\
Appraiser Findings&Page \pageref{sec:appraiserfindings}\\
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\newpage
\begin{center}
\section*{Appraiser Findings\label{sec:appraiserfindings}}
\end{center}
\textbf{Inspection~Type:}~~\hfill \textbf{Insp.~Date:}~~\hfill \textbf{Present~at~Inspection:}~~

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\textbf{Did you make any changes/corrections to the property record as a result of the inspection noted above? (if yes, please list changes)}

\hspace{\the\defaultparindent}


\end{minipage}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\textbf{Did you contact the complainant regarding the complaint? (if yes, specify date and nature of \mbox{contact})}

\hspace{\the\defaultparindent}

\end{minipage}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\textbf{What evidence did you consider when reviewing the value for this property?}

\hspace{\the\defaultparindent}

\end{minipage}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\textbf{Briefly explain all the facts considered and conclusions you made regarding the validity of the evidence submitted along with any evidence you have provided through your work:}

\hspace{\the\defaultparindent}

\end{minipage}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\textbf{Please state your recommendation of value below:}
\nopagebreak
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\nopagebreak
\begin{center}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {rlrrrr}
\toprule
&\textbf{Parcel}&\textbf{Land}&\textbf{Building}&\textbf{OBXF}&\textbf{TOTAL}\\
\cmidrule{2-6}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{{\ldots continued from previous page}}\\
&\textbf{Parcel}&\textbf{Land}&\textbf{Building}&\textbf{OBXF}&\textbf{TOTAL}\\
\cmidrule{2-6}
\endhead
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page\ldots}}\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
1.)&REMOVED&\$0&\$0&\$0&\$0\\

\cmidrule{2-6}
\addlinespace
&TOTALS&\$0&\$0&\$0&\textbf{\$0}\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{center}

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{lXr}
Respectfully Submitted,&&\\
\\
\includegraphics[draft]{removed.png}&&\includegraphics[draft]{removed.png}\\
\\
ZEIGLER JR., GARY&&FROST, JASON\\
\\
Appraiser&&Reviewer\\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, the problem is not yours, it is from `fancyhdr.sty` that uses old font commands:

```
\if@twoside
  \fancyhead[el,or]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[er,ol]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\leftmark}}
\else
  \fancyhead[l]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[r]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\leftmark}}
\fi
```

Those lines should be

```
\if@twoside
  \fancyhead[el,or]{\fancyplain{}{\slshape\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[er,ol]{\fancyplain{}{\slshape\leftmark}}
\else
  \fancyhead[l]{\fancyplain{}{\slshape\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[r]{\fancyplain{}{\slshape\leftmark}}
\fi
```

Since the problem is not really from your document, the one really being nagged is the author of `fancyhdr`; to prevent the complaints, use `\fancyhf{}` (to clear all predefined fields, in particular, the ones producing complaints) before your definitions:

```
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\textbf{\Large Board~of~Revision~Standard~Report}}
\cfoot{\textbf{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
```

By the way, it's better to use the more modern interface with `\fancyhead`, `\fancyfoot`, as in

```
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{\Large Board~of~Revision~Standard~Report}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
```

Comment: @percusse simply using `\fancyhf{}` before the customized  definitions (which is always a good idea), suppresses the complaints.

Comment: Gonzalo, I implemented all your suggestions above and the output is now clean for my current set of test records.  Would you mind sharing the steps you used to track this issue down?  The line numbers referenced in the warnings clearly had nothing to do with the actual issue, and did not reference the fancyhdr.sty file that I can see.

Comment: @Hath1 Of course. I'll add a comment,  but I can't do it right now (I have a lecture and then I'll go home).